# Is there any way to load an external URL in angular 6 dialog without using iframe,object or embed?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, popup

- iframe, object and embed are vulnerable for XSS
- accepting external URL using angular sanitizer service and bypassing safeURL is also risky
- I need complete custom popup which embed external url in it

Comment: The answer is no. Iframe with headers set to lock it down is best you can do.

Comment: @epascarello what does it mean? can you please explain "headers set to lock"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

Comment: @epascarello thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to just use an iframe, but you could create an angular component that will sanitize the external url before rendering it in the iframe.‍♂️